# how to detect if windows mobile device has camera ? c#

Tags: c#, camera, windows-mobile-6

how I can detect if the device has a camera before calling the method camera.showDialog ();?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [SystemState.CameraPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.camerapresent.aspx) property.

Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.SystemState.CameraPresent